# pandas - roll a window on all columns of a dataframe with custom function and pass extra parameters

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe with 7 columns and about 1000000 rows.

```
   column1   column2   column3   column4   column5   column6   column7
0        0  0.361690  0.377105  0.361405  0.374822  0.001909  0.368755   
1        1  0.367399  0.376820  0.338567  0.356552  0.068900  0.359834   
2        2  0.357122  0.390237  0.353982  0.359121  0.036614  0.365116   
3        3  0.364545  0.405652  0.360263  0.387953  0.070556  0.379603
```

Here is a very simple example of a custom function (for demonstration) i can use on only ONE column.

```
def customFunction(df):
    if (df.mean() >= 0.5):
       result = True
    else:
       result = False
    return result

dataFrame["column8"] = dataFrame["column2"].rolling(window=2000).apply(customFunction)
```

Is there an efficient way to roll a window (of a certain size) on all columns of the dataframe and pass some other parameters as well. Something like this

```
def customRollingFunctionWithMultipleColumns(dataFrame1, dataFrame2):
     dataFrame1 = functionToNormalizeData(dataFrame1)
     dataFrame1["column8"] = dataFrame2["compareAgainst"]
     dataFrame1["column9"] = np.where(((dataFrame1['column8'] <= dataFrame1['column2']) & (dataFrame1['column8'] >= dataFrame1['column3'])), 1, 0)

     result = dataFrame1.column9.sum()
     return result

dataFrame["column8"] = dataFrame.rolling(window=2000).apply(customRollingFunctionWithMultipleColumns(dataFrameWith2000Rows, dataFrame2))
```

Comment: Your question is bit too generic. An answer will depend on that what you want to do in the `customRollingFunctionWithMultipleColumns` function. Can you provide more details?

Comment: hei @MaxU i just edited the customRollingFunctionWithMultipleColumns function with more details of what is actually happening. do you have any suggestions?

Comment: It's much better now - let me try to find an appropriate solution

Comment: let me reframe the question as best as i can: How to roll a window of 2000 rows on all columns and pass that window as a dataframe to another functions where some logic happens then return back the result and save it in a new column under the same row in the original dataframe. @MaxU

Comment: I've added a simple solution, which uses `lambda` function. Please pay attention at rewritten `customRollingFunctionWithMultipleColumns` function - it does almost the same as yours, but it compares (`column2 <= compareAgainst <= column3`) - otherwise it wouldn't fit, because in your snippet (`column3 >= column2`) for all rows

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IIUC you can do this:

```
def customRollingFunctionWithMultipleColumns(df1, df2):
    qry = "column2 <= @df2.compareAgainst and @df2.compareAgainst <= column3"
    return (df.eval(qry)*1).sum()

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'compareAgainst':(df.column3 + df.column2)/2})
df2.loc[[0,3]] *= 2

In [84]: df.rolling(window=2).apply(lambda x: customRollingFunctionWithMultipleColumns(x, df2))
Out[84]:
   column1  column2  column3  column4  column5  column6  column7
0      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN
1      2.0      2.0      2.0      2.0      2.0      2.0      2.0
2      2.0      2.0      2.0      2.0      2.0      2.0      2.0
3      2.0      2.0      2.0      2.0      2.0      2.0      2.0
```

Comment: Thank you, it is exactly the result i wanted :)

Comment: @RaduS, glad i could help :-)